# Bootstrap place all div in single line

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to place userlist in left side and searchbox and button in right side in same line

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="user-title">User List-5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="input-group user-search-box col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
      <span class="input-group-addon input-search-custom-adon" ><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="add-new-user col-md-6">
      <a class="btn  add-new-user" href="#" role="button">ADD NEW USER</a>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

i have tried by using float:left then add button will show first instead of search box
can any one help me

Comment: A fiddle would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code work for you perfect 
 HTML is like this

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="user-title">User List-5</div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-8 right-col">
         <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
            <span class="input-group-addon input-search-custom-adon"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         </div>
         <div class="add-new-user"> <a class="btn  add-new-user" href="#" role="button">ADD NEW USER</a></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

and CSS like this

```
  .right-col {
    display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  .input-group {
    max-width: 520px;
  }
```

Comment: @iCoders I don't see why you should be using flex when it can be achieved by simple bootstrap classes. Anyways Cheers.!

Comment: we are not in 2010 anymore.. it increase DOM. flex give you clear solution.

Comment: Agreed but it restricts your search bar to a max of 520px on even larger viewports like imac when u don't need any extra css to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I editted your code in fiddle. Seems to be having what you needed but only after 992px of viewport width. The reason for this is that you are using col-md-4 so the layout will hold tru only after that viewport width.

If you wish that it should hold true for smaller screens as well pls try using

```
col-sm-4 or col-xs-4 for user list

col-sm-8 or col-xs-8 for search and button div
```

**Note : Once you specify md for lower viewports it takes full width of 12 columns/100% of container.**

If you need it after 992 px only then here is the updated code bootstrap way :P. 
you probably got it wrong by combining input-group with col class

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="user-title">User List-5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group user-search-box">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
          <span class="input-group-addon input-search-custom-adon"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="add-new-user">
          <a class="btn  add-new-user" href="#" role="button">ADD NEW USER</a>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thnaks for the answer

Comment: you may accept the answer if you feel it solves your purpose. Thanks in Advance !! :)

Comment: @iCoders Please mark the question as solved and accept the answer as a correct solution or you can let me know if something else is needed as part of this :)

Comment: how to place searchbox and add button right.now its not in right its in middle

Comment: Reduce the button size to 2  columns instead of 6 and then add an offset of 4 to the search container. Editted the code above

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is float the two elements next to each other with `float: left` on the search box, and `float: right` on the button. If you don't want to use any CSS, you can also use the the built-in Bootstrap [helper classes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_helper_classes.htm) `pull-left` and `pull-right`. Simply set `pull-left` on the search box, and `pull-right` on the button:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="user-title">User List-5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="input-group user-search-box col-md-6 pull-left">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
      <span class="input-group-addon input-search-custom-adon" ><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="add-new-user col-md-6 pull-right">
      <a class="btn  add-new-user" href="#" role="button">ADD NEW USER</a>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

I've created a BootPly showing this [here](http://www.bootply.com/Rsm8QiSeBM).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: One should not use col layout classes in conjunction with input group as it breaks the float that is core of bootstrap. col-md-6 should be a wrapper and input group contained inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Just force the float at left for the user box :

**CSS**:

`.user-search-box{float:left !important}`

**Fiddle** : http://www.bootply.com/9CEJvzG4y6

**And** :

You forgot to insert a `.row` after the `col-md-8`